# Beanstalk doese it make sense to open new tube

Tags: php, laravel, queue, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I use beanstalk in the laravel project and it works very stable. But for each user, I have to take a long sequence of operations. In this case, I can not proceed to the operation of the second user until the operation of the first user is finished. Does it make a difference to open a new TUBE for each user?

hope the image link will help more to explain what I mean

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRhq2.png

Thanks

Comment: Like every tech answer: It depends. Does it need to go fast? because since you are using a queue it will be handled in the background and for most operations like making pdf's or sending emails it does not matter if that stuff is done after a delay. So you need to provide more info if you want a better answer.

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply. There are 5 different API connections in the project and each has different time constraints. As an example workflow; say that the first user has sent a request to the "A" API and should wait 2 minutes before sending the second request. Another user sends different requests to the "A" and "B" APIs. There are different waiting times for them and I take the queue according to the order of requests. What I want to do is that the operations of the first user are performed while the second user does not expect the operations of the first user to be finished.

Comment: That is a tricky situation. But if it where me i would probably make queues not per user but per type of operation. For example make a high and low priority queue . The high queue contains operations that are relatively fast and are necessary to move forward in your application. And all the slow or without time constraint operations should go on the low 
 priority queue.

Comment: @Christophvh thanks for your advice. Another question is can I open Tube's with laravel project on the fly? Ihave search the several tutorials and they all say that the tube name must be writen on the config file.